# Loading .sid files in QGIS 2.18.3 for Ubuntu

Tags: qgis, raster, ubuntu

I just installed QGIS 2.18.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 and just realized that .SID files are not accepted as a valid file format for raster images.

Is it possible that there is a library missing from the distro from ubuntugis?